# How to listen or get json in React app from another app making a POST localhost?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a C# app that does a POST with json to http://localhost:9090/myend

```
{
  "eqid": "123",
  "cnid": "123",
  "report":{
    "somevalue": "123",
    "anothervalue": "123
}
```

I have react app that runs on port 3001

And I have express running on port 9090

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()
const PORT = 9090

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

app.post("/myend", (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4))
  res.status(200).end() // Responding is important
})
```

I can see that post in console in the express but how do I get that json in react app? Do I even need express?

Comment: let me clarify: you send an JSON from your C# app to your express backend and expect the result on your react app?

Comment: Yes correct. One more thing I can do a websockets just not sure how.

Comment: well that is not possible. what you want is websocket. you can use https://socket.io/ There is for sure an reactjs library for socket io

Comment: So any links to how I can receive/listen using websockets & send it to my react app

Answer (score 0):

> res.end([data] [, encoding]) 
> Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core, specifically the response.end() method of http.ServerResponse. 
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().

use [res.send](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)

- Sends the HTTP response.
- The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array.

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()
const PORT = 9090

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

app.post("/elsdcp", (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4))
  res.status(200).send(req.body)
})
```

> You can also use [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json).

---

in react App

use [fetch](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/01/react-fetch-http-post-request-examples) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

for example

```js
// fetch
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
}; 

fetch('https://stackoverflow.example.com/fetch/post', requestOptions)
    .then(response => this.setState({ articleId: response.data.id }));
```

```
// axios
const article = { title: 'React POST Request Example' };
axios.post('https://stackoverflow.example.com/fetch/post', article)
    .then(response => this.setState({ articleId: response.data.id }));
```

Comment: So how do I get this in my react app?

Comment: Received as the result of http post. Here's an example. [react-post-example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/17/react-axios-http-post-request-examples)

Comment: I am not posting I am trying to receive what is posted to http://localhost:9090/elsdcp. I know I need to use websokets just not sure how

Comment: Is it sending data from the server to the client now?

Comment: It is common for the server to transmit data according to the client's request. In order for the client to carry the server data, use a pub/sub structured protocol such as mqtt.